# 02 Taurus no acceleration, miss shifting, and no power

Tags: automatic-transmission, sensor, taurus, egr, throttle-position-sensor

I have a 2002 Taurus 3.0 OHV.  I'm getting no acceleration, miss shifting, and no power. I installed a new EGR control valve, differential pressure sensor, air filter, and coolant temperature sensor, and cleared codes, but still got a P1409 (egr related). This all started after the car ran hotter than 200 degrees.

Comment: https://www.autocodes.com/p1409_ford.html

Did you replace the EGR solenoid? Wires/connections look good?